# How to make this a function?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to put this in a function:

```
Dim o As Object
o = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
o.Navigate2("http://example.org", "", "", "", "")
```

I've tried this code, yet it doesn't compile:

```
Public Function goto(website)

Dim o As Object
o = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
o.Navigate2("" & website & "", "", "", "", "")

End Function
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You should post the exception you're getting, or what you mean by "without any luck"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've essentially got it right. However, you can't use reserved keywords such as `goto` for your function name, which is one of the reasons for this to fail.

Also don't forget to name the types of your parameters and a return type. If you don't need a return type, use a sub procedure instead (which is essentially a function without a return value):

```
Public Sub Browse(website As String)
    ' This is simply your existing code:
    Dim o As Object
    o = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    o.Navigate2(website, "", "", "", "")
End Sub
```

Comment: When I use that, it automatically convert it to "Public Sub Browse(ByVal website As String)" is it normal ?

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly fine and makes it clear that you're passing "by value" rather than "by reference". You could change it to `ByRef`though (avoids copying the string, since it's not changed anyway).